# SELENIUM web-driver -> click button in "li" that has "span-classname"

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying my selenium webdriver in java to click the **Next Day** button on "soccer24.com"

This is the element-code:

```
   `<span class="day tomorrow" title="Next day" 
      onclick="change_date('tomorrow'); e_t.track_click('iframe-bookmark- 
       click', 'calendar-arrow-next');"><span class="inner"><span 
    class="arrow"></span></span></span>`
```

At the moment I am trying this:

```
    `WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("Day tomorrow"));
    el.click();`
```

Apologize for bad questioning but I'm a novice.

Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrongly used the class name as id.So, you need to use the Xpath as below

```
//li[@id='ifmenu-calendar']//span[@class='day tomorrow']
```

**Code:**

```
WebElement el=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='ifmenu-calendar']//span[@class='day tomorrow']"));

el.click();
```

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME. THANK U VERY MUCH. all this syntax is a bit complicated . THANK U ALSO TO EVERYBODY HAVING A GO

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark button..

Comment: hey subburaj, PROBLEM IS: it doesnt give an error, but the wanted result isnt achieved either.  the button is clicked supposedly, the code doesnt change. i still get the code for "today" . any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Day Tomorrow is your class name,not an Id.Use the below code and Let me know in case you face any issue.

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='day tomorrow' and @title='Next Day']"));
el.click();
```

Or

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Next Day']"));
el.click();
```

Comment: unfortunately this didnt work either :/  thanks anyway  ... it always shuts down , saying element not found., I also tried "day tomorrow"

Comment: You should not use the class name locator when the class attribute has multiple class name (compound class]

Comment: Try the edited answer, Please post the error message in case ou get any. Thanks

Comment: this is what i get :  [ERROR - 2018-08-14T17:44:09.198Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1534268649076

  phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error

Comment: i think it should work, but there is a little typo mistake in the second answer, he wrote title='Next Day'] but your title is 'Next day' !  just change the capital letter!  you could also try just to you use : WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='day tomorrow']"));